# Fast multi-dimensional Walsh-Hadamard transforms in Julia?

Tags: julia

I was looking for a fast implementation of FWHT(Fast Walsh-Hadamard transformation) to understand it and implement it in python (implementation should be able to handle an n-dimensional array and should be able to apply the transformation on any specific set of dimensions).

I came across the Julia implementation (https://github.com/stevengj/Hadamard.jl) which seems to be pretty good but as I am new to Julia I am not able to understand a part of the code:

```
for (Tr,Tc,fftw,lib) in ((:Float64,:Complex128,"fftw",FFTW.libfftw),
                     (:Float32,:Complex64,"fftwf",FFTW.libfftwf))
    @eval function Plan_Hadamard{N}(X::StridedArray{$Tc,N}, Y::StridedArray{$Tc,N},
                             region, flags::Unsigned, timelimit::Real,
                             bitreverse::Bool)
        set_timelimit($Tr, timelimit)
        dims, howmany = dims_howmany(X, Y, [size(X)...], region)
        dims = hadamardize(dims, bitreverse)
        plan = ccall(($(string(fftw,"_plan_guru64_dft")),$lib),
                 PlanPtr,
                 (Int32, Ptr{Int}, Int32, Ptr{Int},
                  Ptr{$Tc}, Ptr{$Tc}, Int32, UInt32),
                 size(dims,2), dims, size(howmany,2), howmany,
                 X, Y, FFTW.FORWARD, flags)
        set_timelimit($Tr, NO_TIMELIMIT)
            if plan == C_NULL
                error("FFTW could not create plan") # shouldn't normally happen
            end
        return cFFTWPlan{$Tc,FFTW.FORWARD,X===Y,N}(plan, flags, region, X, Y)
    end

    @eval function Plan_Hadamard{N}(X::StridedArray{$Tr,N}, Y::StridedArray{$Tr,N},
                             region, flags::Unsigned, timelimit::Real,
                             bitreverse::Bool)
        set_timelimit($Tr, timelimit)
        dims, howmany = dims_howmany(X, Y, [size(X)...], region)
        dims = hadamardize(dims, bitreverse)
        kind = Array{Int32}(size(dims,2))
        kind[:] = R2HC
        plan = ccall(($(string(fftw,"_plan_guru64_r2r")),$lib),
                 PlanPtr,
                 (Int32, Ptr{Int}, Int32, Ptr{Int},
                  Ptr{$Tr}, Ptr{$Tr}, Ptr{Int32}, UInt32),
                 size(dims,2), dims, size(howmany,2), howmany,
                 X, Y, kind, flags)
        set_timelimit($Tr, NO_TIMELIMIT)
        if plan == C_NULL
            error("FFTW could not create plan") # shouldn't normally happen
        end
        return r2rFFTWPlan{$Tr,(map(Int,kind)...),X===Y,N}(plan, flags, region, X, Y)
    end
end
```

In the above code what is the plan variable, how is it used, and where can I find its implementation?

What are the inputs in the curly braces for the below line?

```
cFFTWPlan{$Tc,FFTW.FORWARD,X===Y,N}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is constructing an [FFTW "plan"](http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Introduction.html) to perform a multidimensional FFT.  The `cFFTWPlan` type is a wrapper around the C `fftw_plan` pointer, and is implemented in the [FFTW.jl module](https://github.com/JuliaMath/FFTW.jl).  The arguments in curly braces are Julia [type parameters](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Parametric-Types-1): in this case, indicating the number type (`Tc`), the FFTW transform direction `FORWARD`, whether the transform is in-place (`X===Y`), and the dimensionality of the transform (`N`).   There are two methods here, one for an FWHT of complex-number data that creates a `cFFTWPlan` (which calls [`fftw_plan_guru_dft`](http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Guru-Complex-DFTs.html)) and one for real-number data that creates an `r2rFFTWPlan` (which calls [fftw_plan_guru_r2r](http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Guru-Real_002dto_002dreal-Transforms.html)).  (These internal types of FFTW.jl are undocumented.   The low-level C calls directly to the FFTW library are documented in the FFTW manual.

It should, in principle, be possible to make similar calls to FFTW for NumPy arrays.  However, the existing [pyFFTW wrappers](https://pypi.org/project/pyFFTW/) don't seem to support FFTW's r2r transforms (needed for FWHTs of real data), so you'd have to add that.

Or you could call the Julia Hadamard.jl module from Python via the [pyjulia package](https://github.com/JuliaPy/pyjulia).  Or you could use some other Python FWHT package, like https://github.com/FALCONN-LIB/FFHT

Answer (score 1):

There is a booklet that explains it in some basic intuitive ways.
[WHT Booklet](https://archive.org/details/whtebook-archive)
For example the 2-point transform of [a,b] is [a+b,a-b] which can be inverted by the same action again [(a+b)+(a-b),(a+b)-(a-b])=[2a,2b]. It then explains how to construct the 4-point transform from 2 2-point transforms etc.